# Get and save enum using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a project in which I have some assemblies which implement an abstract class.

Each assembly has a public enum called ResultEnum.
This ResultEnum's value is stored in a database as an int.

I have another web project which displays some info, and I want it to also display this int's string representation - the name of the corresponding value from the ResultEnum.

What I want to do is, using MEF, load all the relevant assemblies (no problem here), search for this enum using reflection (no problem here also) and then to store the enum in some way, and cache it in order to avoid all this process the next time I want to convert the int from the database to the string representation (and the other way around if necessary) since I have several thousands of records in my db table.

```
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(path));
_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

try
{
    _container.ComposeParts(this);
}
catch (CompositionException compositionException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
}

foreach (var task in myTasks)
{
    TaskAbstract instance = (TaskAbstract)task.CreateExport().Value;

    MemberInfo[] infos = instance.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (MemberInfo member in infos.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("ResultEnum")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(member);                    
    }
}
```

What do you suggest the next move should be?
How should I store/cache it?

Thanks

Comment: A dictionary from int to string comes to my mind, no?

Comment: I agree, But question is how do I iterate over the values and names of the enumerator. And, is there a better solution than a dictionary

Comment: Are you needing to do these types of operations a lot?  If so, you might want to consider using something like a subclassable enum or similar technique.  I've written about Subclassable Enums at http://tyreejackson.com/subclassable-enums/ .  For example, I use StringIntegerEnum subtypes to handle mapping between dual underlying values for each enum.

Comment: @TyreeJackson this solution seems interesting, I really do need an 'abstract' enumerator. I'll read it again and consider implementing this change, thanks:)

Comment: @Alonzzo2 Cool.  I'll post an answer about Subclassable enums then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i've written the code eventually:

```
        resultEnumsForTasks = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<UInt16, string>>();
        foreach (var task in myTasks)
        {
            Dictionary<UInt16, string> _enum =  new Dictionary<UInt16,string>();
            TaskAbstract instance = (TaskAbstract)task.CreateExport().Value;
            MemberInfo resultEnum = instance.GetType().GetMember("ResultEnum").FirstOrDefault();
            if (resultEnum == null)
                continue;

            string[] names = Enum.GetNames(resultEnum as Type);
            IList<int> vals = (IList<int>)Enum.GetValues(resultEnum as Type);
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                _enum.Add(Convert.ToUInt16(vals[i]), names[i]);
            }
            resultEnumsForTasks.Add(instance.GetType().Name, _enum);
        }
```

It's very similar to @n.turakulov 's solution, however his solution didn't work for me since I got an empty list of PropertyInfo for some reason...

Thanks for everyone who assisted!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Thomas's answer:

As using reflection you can get exact int value from a property, the name for that concrete value could be gotten using the next expression:

```
var enumValueName = Enum.GetName(member.GetType(), member.GetValue(instance));
```

**UPD**

I really missed that you reflect MemberInfos. To apply my solution you can update you reflection this way:

```
foreach (var task in myTasks)
{
    TaskAbstract instance = (TaskAbstract)task.CreateExport().Value;

// Reflect properties, not all members
    PropertyInfo[] infos = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in infos.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("ResultEnum")))
    {
        var enumValueName = Enum.GetName(prop.GetType(), prop.GetValue(instance));                  
    }
}
```

Or you could cast MemberInfo to PropertyInfo.

Comment: `member.GetType()` will return a subclass of `MemberInfo`, not the type of the member's value.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque is right, when I enter this in the watch windows:

"member.GetValue(instance)"

I get this:

"  member.GetValue(instance) 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Which means it relates to MemberInfo

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solving this problem is to consider using a subclassable enums technique (also sometimes referred to as a polymorphic enum).

I wrote a couple of generic classes specifically to support these kinds of types which you can read about [here](http://tyreejackson.com/subclassable-enums/).  Also, a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4436) has been submitted to the Roslyn compiler team on Github to add support for these types of enums to C#.

Here is an example of a set of subclassable enums that have two underlying types, string and integer, using the classes from my project:

```
public sealed class Status : StringIntegerEnum<Status>
{
    public static readonly Status Active = new Status("active", 1);
    public static readonly Status Inactive = new Status("inactive", 0);

    private Status(string status, int statusCode) : base(status, statusCode) {}
}
```

Note that the string value is **not** the same as the constant name itself, which allows you to have underlying string values with characters that violate the normal naming conventions in C#.

The [`StringIntegerEnum<tStringIntegerEnum>`](https://github.com/TyreeJackson/atomic/blob/master/Atomic.Net/DataTypes/StringIntegerEnum.cs) base class provides `.AllValues`, `.AllNaturalValues` and `.AllStringValues` static methods that you can use to enumerate the list of enum values or both types of their underlying values.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I agree, But question is how do I iterate over the values and names of the enumerator

I assume you mean "enumeration", not "enumerator". You can use the `Enum.GetValues` method:

```
var valuesToNames =
    Enum.GetValues(enumType)
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToDictionary(o => (int)o, o => Enum.GetName(enumType, o));
```

> And, is there a better solution than a dictionary

Better how? I think a dictionary is a fine solution; is there any reason why you would want something else?

Comment: " I assume you mean "enumeration", not "enumerator". "
You're right.
But my problem is with getting the enumType from your example since I don't know the real ResultEnum type - I used reflection to get the member which represents it.
How do I get the real type of the enum while using reflection?
Hope you understood me

Comment: @Alonzzo2, what about `member.PropertyType`? (if it's a property; use FieldType if it's a field, ReturnType if it's a method, etc)

Comment: "MemberInfo doesn't contain a definition for PropertyType.", using the 'watch' window

Comment: @Alonzzo2, you need to cast it to its actual type (PropertyInfo, FieldInfo, MethodInfo, etc). MemberInfo is just the base class for those types.